# Binary quadratic forms - Equivalence and repressentation of integers

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms

If $f,g$ are two binary quadratic forms, $f$ and $g$ are equivalent, if there is an integer matrix $M$ with determinant $\pm1$ such that $G=M^T F M$ where $F,G$ are the matrices that define $f,g$. It is known, that equivalent forms represent the same integers (in fact with same multiplicities). Is the converse also true, i.e., if $f$ and $g$ represent the same integers, are they equivalent? If not, does equivalence hold if also the multiplicities are equal?

Comment: For positive definite binary quadratic forms I would be inclined to say the answer is yes...since each such form is equivalent to a unique reduced one and different reduced ones represent different integers.

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: I was forgetting two examples with differing discriminants: it is well known, and easy, to show that $x^2 + xy+y^2$ and $x^2 + 3 y^2$ represent exactly the same numbers. With indefinite forms, $x^2 + xy-y^2$ and $x^2 -5 y^2$ represent exactly the same numbers.

ORIGINAL: You seem to be restricting to positive forms. If two forms have the same discriminant and represent the same prime numbers, they are either equivalent or "opposite." Here equivalent would mean $\det M = 1,$ opposite would mean $\det M = -1.$

Next, what about differing discriminants? There are a finite number of pairs of forms of different discriminants that represent the same primes, or the same odd primes, or wjhat have you. I and Kaplansky wrote an informal article on this. Hendrik Lenstra's student John Voight, now at Dartmouth, finished the job. Item number 6 at [VOIGHT](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~jvoight/research.html).

Finishing your question is then a matter of checking pairs of forms from Voight's tables and seeing how they compare on composite numbers. My guess is that perfect agreement is impossible for differing discriminants.

In comparison, for positive forms in three variables, there are infinitely many pairs of forms, of differing discriminants, that represent the same numbers. However, not with the same multiplicities, this is a difficult result due to Alexander Schiemann. I looked into the matter further a year ago, I think I found all pairs of positive ternaries representing the same numbers. No proof of completeness, though.

Schiemann also found an example in four variables, two distinct forms that represent the same numbers with the same multiplicities. It's in the book by Nipp. I believe the discriminant was 1729. Yes, that's correct, 1729.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have a source for the result about binary quadratic forms with same discriminants? I have checked a few of the forms in the article of Voight, it seems that you are right and perfect agreement is not possible (maybe I have more time later to investigate all the pairs).

Comment: I think it is particularly nice, that the discriminant of the example you mention is such a special number.

Comment: @Martin, the part about primes and the same discriminant is in many number theory books; my favorite is Buell, Binary Quadratic Forms. Added into the answer: there is one positive pair, $x^2 +xy+y^2$ and $x^2 + 3y^2$ represent the same numbers. i think that is the only positive example.

Comment: I have searched for the result about primes and same discriminant in the book from Buell (and others) but did not find it. Do you have a more precise reference?

Comment: @Martin, Buell, page 74, Theorem 4.23. The case when the prime divides the discriminant is on he next page, Theorem 4.24. I see, the prime 2 is separate, Th. 4.25.

Comment: @Martin, for primes (including 2) dividing the discriminant, sometimes only imprimitive forms represent that prime..discriminant $-12,$ the entire class group (primitive forms) is one, $x^2 + 3 y^2.$ However, we have the imprimitive form $2x^2 + 2 x y + 2 y^2$ as well.

Comment: @Martin, Buell was not sufficiently careful in Theorem 4.23. Take prime $59$ and discriminant $-23.$ We see $53^2 \equiv -23 \pmod {236}.$ However, both $(59, 53, 12)$ and $(59,-53,12)$ are equivalent to $(1,1,6),$ the principal form. It's always something. So his word "distinct" may not hold.

Comment: @Martin, David A. Cox, Primes of the Form $x^2 + n y^2,$ Lemma 2.3 on page 25, Exercise 2.27(a) on page 46. Note Cox uses the word equivalent to mean my `equivalent or opposite'

Comment: Thanks, with that I have managed to show it. So in fact it suffices if $f$ and $g$ both represent one prime $p$ and one does not need that $f$ and $g$ represent the same primes.